# Inheritance - What method is being called?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have a class A that extends a class B.

A is defined like this, it also overrides a method of B:

```
class A extends B
{
    public A() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        //does something
    }
}
```

B is defined like this:

```
public class B
{
    public B(){
        doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        //does something
    }
}
```

So if I initialize an object of A, the constructor calls the one of the superclass that calls the method `doSomething()`. But which one will be executed? B's implementation or the overriden one in A?

Comment: What do you think will happen? What makes you think so? What happens when you write such code and execute it?

Comment: To answer your question, it will call the method which is overridden in A.

Answer (score 3):

That is a common bug, only call `final` methods in constructor, the method from `A` will be called.

Btw `Sonar`(if you have it) will trigger a rule here saying that you should not call polymorphic methods inside a constructor.

Comment: Or `private` or `static` which also are not polymorphic.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, good point, call anything that is not polymorphic

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug, it's intended behavior actually. Common bug source maybe...

Comment: @algrid its interesting when u say "intended", what about other languages, do they do the same? And also bug was refering to application code bugs, not java itself

Comment: @Eugene Regarding other languages - Swift does the same thing for example, but Swift has some other means to ensure initialization consistency. C++ does inverse if I'm not mistaken. But the question was about the actual behavior in Java and I just don't see why would one call it a "bug". A bad language design decision in Java - maybe, but that's quite subjective.

Answer (score 0):

If the class Overrides a method, then the overriden method will be called. Try the example below:

```
public class A {
 void doSomething() {
  System.out.println("a");
 }
}
public class B extends A {
 @Override
 void doSomething() {
  System.out.println("b");
 }
}
A a = new B();
a.doSomething(); // will print "b"
```